# angular how to format date without 0 in month

Tags: angular

How do I format the date same format as MM/dd/YYYY but with no 0 in month like , ..Thanks.

```
instead of 02/20/2021
it should be 2/20/2021

#currentCode
{{data.targetDate | date:'MM/dd/YYYY'}}
```

Comment: Not sure, but did you try ‘M/dd/YYYY'?

Comment: does not work , does it not have any drawbacks?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options), the format you want would be `M/d/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if you can use this way , i think your problem will be solved**

```js
console.log("Hello I am codewithharshad");

var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getDate()+ "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" +date.getFullYear()  )
```